# Spring boot security oauth2 authorization_code flow login page not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Hi i am trying to implement OAuth2 using spring security, so far i have managed to implement it using `grant_type=password` i am getting `token, time, refresh token` and resources are guarded as expected.

Now my next step is to use `authorization_code+pkce` implementation.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2), when i replace all the client credentials with my auth server details i get `http://localhost:8080/oauth/login`  `Not Found` message. The request goes something like this `http://localhost:8080/auth/oauth/authorize?client_id=SampleClientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8083/ui2/login&response_type=code&state=5ppnu6`

My Configuration and server files are as follow, this is my first time implemeting oauth on server side so i might be doing very non-sense, please help me correct that.
`AuthorizationServerConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager manager;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("SampleClientId")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "implicit", "refresh_token")
                .scopes(UserDetailsServiceImpl.Role.USER.name(),
                        UserDetailsServiceImpl.Role.MODERATOR.name(),
                        UserDetailsServiceImpl.Role.ADMIN.name())
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/callback", "http://localhost:8083/ui2/login")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(4800);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(manager);
    }


}
```

`BeansConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
public class BeansConfig {
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

}
```

`ResourceServerConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
```

`SecurityConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    public SecurityConfig() {
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        userDetailsService.init(passwordEncoder);
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

`UsersControllers.java`

```
@RestController
public class UsersControllers {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> get() {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("status", "ok");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(map);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/user/me")
    Principal me(Principal principal) {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("status", "ok");
        return principal;
    }
}
```

`UserDetailsImpl.java`

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final List<GrantedAuthority> roles;

    public UserDetailsImpl(String username, String password, List<GrantedAuthority> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

`UserDetailsServiceImpl.java`

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class.getSimpleName());

    public enum Role {
        USER,
        MODERATOR,
        ADMIN
    }

    private final List<UserDetailsImpl> users = new ArrayList<>();


    public UserDetailsServiceImpl() {
    }

    public void init(BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        users.add(new UserDetailsImpl("john", passwordEncoder.encode("doe"), buildUserAuthorities()));
        users.add(new UserDetailsImpl("wow", passwordEncoder.encode("baby"), buildModeratorAuthorities()));
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthorities() {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = new ArrayList<>();
        authorityList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Role.USER.name()));
        return authorityList;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildModeratorAuthorities() {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = new ArrayList<>();
        authorityList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Role.MODERATOR.name()));
        return authorityList;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        for (UserDetailsImpl details : users) {
            if (details.getUsername().equals(s)) {
                LOGGER.warning("Found user: " + s);
                return details;
            }
        }
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + s + " notfound");
    }

    public List<UserDetailsImpl> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

Some of the contents from maven file

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Did you solve this ?. I have the same problem

Comment: i created new app and lucky it worked.